# Convert plain sql to parameteric sql in java

Tags: java

I want generalize method to convert plain sql query to parametric sql in java

I have below method which has been used in project. This has lot of references.

```
    public Object executeQuery(String aQuery) {
    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet r = null;
    try {

        con = getConnection() ;
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        r = stmt.executeQuery(aQuery);

        if (r.next()) {
            //return extracted result;
        }

        return null;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
            "Cannot execute query " + aQuery + " : " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        cleanup(r,stmt,con);
    }
    }

    //=========
    //calling above method
    executeQuery("Update USER set user_id = 15 where user_name='test');
```

I was thinking convert this to parametric sql using java prepared statement. 
Then the method invoke won't change, but query like

```
       Update USER set user_id = 15 where user_name='test'
```

will use java PreparedStatement and  appropriate parameters

```
       Update USER set user_id = ? where user_name=?
```

Is there a way to do this like using Spring or other framework.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to change the method so that It executes query using prepared statement WITHOUT changing method calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then the method invoke won't change

You should *absolutely* change the calling methods. I would *strongly* discourage you from trying to do this manually. If the caller has failed to escape their values properly, you've already got broken SQL - trying to fix that to correct SQL with parameters will be a pain.

I suggest you overload the method, and gradually move the callers from the broken method to the working one. (Deprecate the broken one immediately, of course.)

I realize there may be a lot of callers, and thus a lot of work - but that's just the result of leaving it broken for so long. Tackle the underlying problem now, instead of just putting a sticking plaster over it.

Comment: +1 for silently making me realize the use of 'deprecated'.